# .htaccess script to stop link breaking using 302 instead of hidden redirect

Tags: .htaccess

I have an already ok htaccess script that is designed to forward `/about` to `/about.php` without displaying it, but I was wondering if anyone knew how to modify my `.htaccess` file to to forward requests to `/about.html` to `/about` (using 302 rather than a hidden redirect)

```
CheckSpelling on
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymlinks

DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)\.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule . /%1    [R=302,L]
```

Comment: if i replaced `about` with `(.+)$` for the first one, and with `$1` on the second, would that work for all pages, not just `about`?

Comment: Is the goal to have all requests for `anything.html` be redirected to `anything` where you already have a rule that rewrites `anything` to `index.php`?